# Can I replicate a MySQL database using Netbeans

Tags: mysql, netbeans, database-replication

I want to know whether there is any way to replicate a `MySQL` database by writing java code in `Netbeans`, as we can replicate `MySQL` tables. Please give suggestions..

Comment: Why do you want to write your own replication mechanism instead of using the MySQL built-in?

Comment: Build a master/slave setup using bin logging.  Update your my.cnf to reflect this.  Do it the MySql way.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans is an IDE, used for range of language from java, c/c++ to php.

Answering to your question. Why not?

You can create a Java client that spawn's two MySQL connection to master and slave. Write you own replication logic or data synchronizing logic, keeping in mind about data integrity.

It is your call, but industry rely on the replication feature that come with MySQL itself. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html